# Entity Framework - trying to insert into a table with a foreign key, EF attempts to insert into the original table with the primary key

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

[image]

Hi, there's my Database diagram.

I'm trying to insert rows into Order and OrderItem tables. Insertion into Order table goes fine.
However, when I'm trying to insert into OrderItem table I get an exception. Cannot insert into Product table, ProductId already exists. Why does this happen?

```
Insert code:

db.Orders.Add(newOrder);

db.SaveChanges();

newOrder.OrderItems = products.Convert(newOrder);

foreach (var orderItem in newOrder.OrderItems)
{
     db.OrderItems.Add(orderItem);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

New order object already has a list of order items, and I need only an exception (for productId) if OrderItem record I want to insert doesn't have existing productId in product table, not insert into Product table. How is this fixable ?

Comment: can you put your insert code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross check whether the list of order items has Product entity object as it is a foreign key for the OrderItem table. Also you can try inserting explicitly in child tables like first insert into Order then Order Items taking the Order entity object this should work (Note OrderItem should have Product entity object).

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. OrderItem had a reference to a full Product object, not just its Id.